# string prototype custom method to make use of encodeURIComponent()

Tags: javascript, prototype, encodeuricomponent

I am writing this method `encodedURIComponentValue()` for Javascript string:

the idea is to allow me to call : `"some string".encodedURIComponentValue()`

The code is as:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.encodedURIComponentValue != 'function') {
    String.prototype.encodedURIComponentValue = function (str) {
        if (str && str.length > 0)
            return encodeURIComponent(str);
        else
            return "";
    };
}
```

but in some case it does not work:

```
var encodedVal = $("body").find("option:selected").first().text().encodedURIComponentValue() // text() = "Option1" 

console.log(encodedVal); // I only see "" (empty)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941) helpful as it explains prototype, constructor function and the value of `this`.

In this case I would not advice doing it like you do. You don't own String and modifying it breaks encapsulation. The only "valid" situation would be if you need to implement an existing method to support older browsers (like Object.create). More info on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes).

You could do what you're doing with:

```
encodeURIComponent(
  $("body").find("option:selected").first().text()
);
```

So other then liking the other syntax there really isn't any reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is my stupid mistake - the `str` is the parameter which was never supplied.
So I changed to this and it works:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.encodedURIComponentValue != 'function') {
    String.prototype.encodedURIComponentValue = function () {
        if (this && this.length > 0)
            return encodeURIComponent(this);
        else
            return "";
    };
}
```

Hope I will understand more about `this` keyword in Js

Comment: you don't need the if branch there: encodeURIComponent("")==""